# When I try to add repositories, why are ubuntu's keyservers timing-out?

Tags: repository, dns, routing, keyserver

Something is rendering receiving keys from keyserver.ubuntu.com impossible and I'm not even sure where to begin in trying to resolve this.

As an example, we'll use the Spotify linux app found here: http://www.spotify.com/us/download/previews/

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4E9CFF4E
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4E9CFF4E
gpg: requesting key 4E9CFF4E from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

To be clear, though, this has nothing to do with Spotify. The same result comes from every one of my attempts to grab keys from ubuntu. There is something wrong on my side. As always, any help in tracking this down would be appreciated.

---

Prior to submitting this, I've discovered that the problem is with my DNS and/or router. Currently I have my router configured to use Google DNS (8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4) and in my router logs I'm receiving a flood of DNS errors. The following is an excerpt:

```
(GMT-06:00)02:48:10 Tue Sep 06 2011 syslog: failed dns request len=145,srcip=8.8.4.4, url=_pgpkey-http._tcp.keyserver.ubuntu.com  
(GMT-06:00)02:48:12 Tue Sep 06 2011 syslog: No response for DNS request to server 68.94.156.1 yet. 
(GMT-06:00)02:48:14 Tue Sep 06 2011 syslog: No response for DNS request to server 68.94.157.1 yet. 
(GMT-06:00)02:48:14 Tue Sep 06 2011 syslog: failed dns request len=83,srcip=192.168.0.1, url=keyserver.ubuntu.com.domain.actdsltmp  
(GMT-06:00)02:48:14 Tue Sep 06 2011 syslog: All DNS servers tried, no response. 
(GMT-06:00)02:48:14 Tue Sep 06 2011 syslog: failed dns request len=158,srcip=8.8.4.4, url=keyserver.ubuntu.com.domain.actdsltmp  
(GMT-06:00)02:49:02 Tue Sep 06 2011 syslog: failed dns request len=145,srcip=8.8.4.4, url=_pgpkey-http._tcp.keyserver.ubuntu.com  
(GMT-06:00)02:49:05 Tue Sep 06 2011 syslog: No response for DNS request to server 68.94.156.1 yet. 
(GMT-06:00)02:49:07 Tue Sep 06 2011 syslog: failed dns request len=158,srcip=8.8.4.4, url=keyserver.ubuntu.com.domain.actdsltmp  
(GMT-06:00)02:49:08 Tue Sep 06 2011 syslog: No response for DNS request to server 68.94.157.1 yet. 
(GMT-06:00)02:49:08 Tue Sep 06 2011 syslog: failed dns request len=83,srcip=192.168.0.1, url=keyserver.ubuntu.com.domain.actdsltmp  
(GMT-06:00)02:49:08 Tue Sep 06 2011 syslog: All DNS servers tried, no response.
```

Very confused. I'm not even sure if I'm posting this on the correct StackExchange site now.

Comment: So you have solved changing nameserver?

Comment: No, I haven't solved this at all. I've two nameservers listed in /etc/resolv.conf. 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 -- yet, when I run a traceroute to 8.8.8.8 it completely fails. The router is listed on the first hop and nothing else after that. I've also changed /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf to include "prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;".

Comment: Change you dns to opendsn (208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220) or some other free dsn service, then try again.

Comment: I've also attempted to revert back to dynamic acquisition of DNS via my router and _that_ doesn't even seem to be working. Well, at least not like it should. Something is obviously very messed up here.

Comment: Same results with different DNS services. However, I think I'm narrowing this down. Considering the possibility, now, that I fixed the problem 2 hours ago and that traceroute is returning false fails due to either UFW or router firewall settings. Rebooting and testing now.

Comment: I was wrong. I mean, it _is_ possible that firewall settings are confusing traceroute, but I still cannot get keys from ubuntu and my router is still logging massive DNS failures.

Comment: Shutdown the firewall, and try without.

Comment: Apparently the answer is to spend hours on myriads of troubleshooting only to discover you are blocking yourself via firewalls. Still seems odd that DNS errors would propagate from firewall blockage, but alas... it worked. I'll try to write an appropriate answer to this question by the end of the day. Thanks enzotib.

Answer (score 2):

*(OP has solved the issue and posted answer as a comment)*

> Apparently the answer is to spend hours on myriads of troubleshooting
>   only to discover you are blocking yourself via firewalls. Still seems
>   odd that DNS errors would propagate from firewall blockage, but
>   alas... it worked