# GPG error while doing sudo apt-get update

Tags: 12.04

```
W: GPG error: http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B31B29E5548C16BF

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_yannubuntu_boot-repair_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS  Encountered a section with no Package: header

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_yannubuntu_boot-repair_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en  Encountered a section with no Package: header

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/apt.newrelic.com_debian_dists_newrelic_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS  Encountered a section with no Package: header

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/apt.newrelic.com_debian_dists_newrelic_non-free_i18n_Translation-en  Encountered a section with no Package: header

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS  Encountered a section with no Package: header

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en  Encountered a section with no Package: header

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I did "sudo apt-get clean" .. Still am facing the same error. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey

Comment: i tried that too.. but am facing "keyserver timed out" issue

Comment: first one -> sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com B31B29E5548C16BF

Comment: i followed the 2nd link too.. stil the same error

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60233/when-i-try-to-add-repositories-why-are-ubuntus-keyservers-timing-out