# keyserver timed out with add-apt-repository

Tags: networking, 14.04, apt, xubuntu

I cannot `add-apt-repository` because the Ubuntu keyserver times out:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpxzw15cei/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpxzw15cei/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E1DF1F24 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error

$ uname -a
Linux gkistner-dt3 4.2.0-36-generic #41~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 19 17:03:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I'm running Xubuntu. Per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/60233/11844) I have checked and found that Xubuntu has no firewall. Per comments on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/757714/11844) I am not behind a corporate proxy (though I am on a corporate LAN that NATs all global traffic); I **am** able to directly `telnet keyserver.ubuntu.com 80`.

If I try to hack in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/134943/11844) I get a similar result:

```
$ sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E1DF1F24
gpg: directory `/home/gkistner/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/home/gkistner/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/home/gkistner/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/home/gkistner/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/home/gkistner/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E1DF1F24 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

How do I add this repository?

Comment: Are you running in a VM?

Comment: @bc2946088 I am not running in a VM.

Comment: What version of Kubuntu are you on, have you tried a different key server?

Comment: Nevermind, just read 14.04 -- try to use hkp://keys.gnupg.net

Comment: @bc2946088 Attempting `sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net:80 --recv-keys E1DF1F24` eventually appears to succeed, but I cannot then re-run the initial `add-apt-repository` command successfully. (It still tries to request the key.)

Comment: You'll need to use apt-key adv to add it

Comment: @bc2946088 And then what? I just `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E1DF1F24` (which worked) but then when I run the original command it still fails in the same way.

Comment: In my case was a proxy issue, solved setting the environment variables and [`sudo -E`](https://askubuntu.com/a/102505/349837).

Answer (score 0):

A coworker discovered that there is some sort of weird networking going on at our site. Running the original command multiple times in a row `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y` repeatedly timed out (after 60s+ of delay each time) and then, magically, it succeeded. Same command, no change to any settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
```

If it works then cheers :D.
If it don't worked then use :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
```

and close your terminal window instantly.Now open terminal again and use the command :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
```

now,that's it.